# How to set configuration data inside alias tasks

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Sorry for the mistakes I've made, I'm not Englishman.

I can't set understand why my code doesn't work correctly (I'm not good at JS). I want manually set project folders according to parameter which I pass through cli. Well..it is my action:

```
$ grunt --project=default
```

My scraps from the Gruntfile.js:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  ...
  sass: {
    main: {
      options: {
        style: 'nested',
      },
      files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= path %>',
        src: ['*.scss'],
        dest: '<%= path %>',
        ext: '.css'
      }]
    }
  },

  watch: {
    sass: {
      files: '<%= path %>/**/*.scss',
      tasks: ['sass'],
      options: {
        livereload: true,
      },
    },
  },

  ...
});

grunt.registerTask('default','', function() {
  // Get project name
  var project = grunt.option('project') || 'default';
  ....
  if (project == 'default') {
    grunt.config.set('path', '../server/www/webapp.com/css');
  }
  ...
  if (project && development && !production) {
    grunt.task.run('watch:sass');
  }
}
```

Task run and everything seems to be ok, for example when I change the *.scss files in the project folder I set up above, `watch` task really detect the changes correctly, but `sass` task output nothing(. However, when I add `path` key within `grunt.initConfg({});` everything works ok.

Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the same answer I gave on https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/1032...

This is because the watch task, by default, spawns tasks in a child process. So your call to grunt.config.set only modifies that config object in the current process and not the child processes. To disable the watch from spawning tasks use the `spawn: false` option.

```
watch: {
  sass: {
    options: { spawn: false },
    files: '<%= path %>/**/*.scss', // perfect!
    tasks: ['sass'],
  },
},
```

Comment: Thank you! At the github it was me)